# classnotfoundException getting if i start activity which is in dynamic module after successful download

Tags: java, android, android-app-bundle

From internal test i could download the dynamic feature module. After successful download i am opening activity which is in dynamic module using package name but i got class not found exception. And i checked APK size but size is not increased. below is my code. Please Help

below is my code for download the module. i used from internal testing which is available in playstore.

```
     public void loadFeatureTwo() {
    // Builds a request to install the feature1 module
    SplitInstallRequest request =
            SplitInstallRequest
                    .newBuilder()
                    // You can download multiple on demand modules per
                    // request by invoking the following method for each
                    // module you want to install.
                    .addModule("feature2")
                    .build();

    // Begin the installation of the feature1 module and handle success/failure
    splitInstallManager
            .startInstall(request)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Integer integer) {
                    // Module download successful
                   /* Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(getPackageName(), "com.bapspatil.feature2.FeatureTwoActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);*/

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "successfully download feature2: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Class.forName("com.bapspatil.feature2.FeatureTwoActivity"));
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                    // Module download failed; handle the error here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't download feature: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Did you integrate with SplitCompat? https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#access_downloaded_modules

Comment: @Pierre Thank you very much. I did not place that.

Comment: @Pierre still i am getting this exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.bapspatil.feature2.FeatureTwoActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.imimobile.androidappbundledemo-xo4sNaGIZ60bGZFxT5o_GQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.imimobile.androidappbundledemo-xo4sNaGIZ60bGZFxT5o_GQ==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.imimobile.androidappbundledemo-xo4sNaGIZ60bGZFxT5o_GQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.imimobile.androidappbundledemo-xo4sNaGIZ60bGZFxT5o_GQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]

Comment: @Pierre i added this line in app module manifest  android:name="com.google.android.play.core.splitcompat.SplitCompatApplication"

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem and what i found is sometimes when you create project from android studio your dynamic module not put the
`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` in your module's `build.gradle` file. Please verify it and if not present apply it in modules gradle file.

If you still not able to find the error please check below links :
1. [How to create dynamic module?](https://www.learnforexample.co.in/2019/10/how-to-create-dynamic-module.html)
2. [How to download dynamic module ?](https://www.learnforexample.co.in/2019/10/how-to-download-dynamic-module.html)

Comment: man, I'm gonna give you a pizza, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you integrate with [SplitCompat](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#access_downloaded_modules) correctly.

In particular, you seem not to be listening to the correct event. You should call `registerListener` and provide a custom `SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener`. Check out the examples of the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#java)

```
// Creates a listener for request status updates.
SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener listener = state -> {
    if (state.sessionId() == mySessionId) {
      // Read the status of the request to handle the state update.
    }
};

// Registers the listener.
splitInstallManager.registerListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is incomplete. You must use `SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener`.
There are 2 things that you need to ensure:

1. Session id is same as yours.
2. Status obtained is `SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED`.

When the above two points are ensured it is only then you can proceed with opening/accessing your dynamic module.

I saw this question now but this should definitely work.

Related code is below:

```
int mSessionId = 0; 
SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener splitInstallStateUpdatedListener = new SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStateUpdate(SplitInstallSessionState state) {
                    // Only if session id matches the one that is ours 
                    // and also the state is "Installed" that we proceed 
                    // with opening our dynamic activity.
                    if (state.sessionId() == mySessionId) {
                            if(state.status() == SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED) {
                                startDynamicFeatureActivity();
                            }
                    }
                }
            };
            splitInstallManager.registerListener(splitInstallStateUpdatedListener);

splitInstallManager.startInstall(request)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(sessionId -> mySessionId = sessionId);
```